# File.exists() = false. Хотя путь правильный

Tags: java, android, файлы

Вот код:

```
        File bookFile = new File(FileName);
        Log.i("Message", String.valueOf(bookFile));
        Log.i("Message", String.valueOf(bookFile.exists()));
        if(bookFile.exists()) {
            flag_find_book = true;
            pdfViewBook.fromFile(bookFile)
                    .defaultPage(pageNumber)
                    .onPageChange(ReadBookFragment.this)
                    .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                    .onLoad(this)
                    .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(getActivity()))
                    .enableAntialiasing(true)
                    .spacing(10)
                    .enableAntialiasing(true)
                    .pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.WIDTH)
                    .nightMode(toggleButtonNightModReadPDF.isChecked())
                    .load();
        }
        else {
            textViewTimerRead.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            toggleButtonNightModReadPDF.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.BookNotFound), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            flag_find_book = false;
        }
```

Вот ЛОГ:

```
D/com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore: Starting PdfiumAndroid 1.9.0

I/Message: /root_files/storage/3C49-7D73/Books/45 татуировок менеджера.pdf
I/Message: false

D/ViewRootImpl[Toast]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.sf.lcd_density"
W/ograms.bookstat: type=1400 audit(0.0:110249): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:graphics_config_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1327 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:graphics_config_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
E/InputTransport: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
I/Toast: Show toast from OpPackageName:com.toprograms.bookstat, PackageName:com.toprograms.bookstat
D/HWUIExtension: MTKProgramCache.generateProgram: 103079215104
D/HWUIExtension: createProgram 0x0000001800000000, binary 0x80ac93cf, length 11105, format 37168 within 898ns
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=120KB, data=117KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=120KB, data=117KB
I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x813de800,api=1)
D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x813de800)
D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x80a06f00) (w:296 h:95 s:320 f:0x1 u:b00)
I/zygote: Compiler allocated 5MB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
I/zygote: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out: e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
W/Ads: Error while pinging URL: https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/gen_204?is_aia=false&id=gmob-apps-report-exception&os=8.1.0&api=27&device=Xiaomi%20Redmi%206A&js=afma-sdk-a-v16187999.15000000.1&appid=com.toprograms.bookstat&exceptiontype=com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.a&stacktrace=com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.a%3A%20Unable%20to%20obtain%20a%20JavascriptEngine.%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.o.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A1)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.promise.g.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.h.run(Unknown%20Source%3A4)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ab.execute(Unknown%20Source%3A0)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.x.run(Unknown%20Source%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.w.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ae.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A6)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.promise.e.d(Unknown%20Source%3A7)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.at.a(Unknown%20Source%3A7)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.promise.g.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.h.run(Unknown%20Source%3A4)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ab.execute(Unknown%20Source%3A0)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.x.run(Unknown%20Source%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.w.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ae.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A6)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.promise.e.d(Unknown%20Source%3A7)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.ad.run(Unknown%20Source%3A5)%0A%09at%20android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java%3A794)%0A%09at%20android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java%3A99)%0A%09at%20aam.a(Unknown%20Source%3A0)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.e.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A1)%0A%09at%20aam.dispatchMessage(Unknown%20Source%3A0)%0A%09at%20android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java%3A176)%0A%09at%20android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java%3A6662)%0A%09at%20java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native%20Method)%0A%09at%20com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit%24MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java%3A547)%0A%09at%20com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java%3A873)%0A&eids=318482963%2C318475418%2C%2C318482077%2C318484496%2C318482761%2C318484676%2C318484568%2C318483611%2C318485399&exceptionkey=ConfigLoader.maybeFetchNewAppSettings&cl=249178941&rc=dev&session_id=5532137493713157666&sampling_rate=1&pb_tm=1.0. Unable to resolve host "pagead2.googlesyndication.com": No address associated with hostname
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x813de800,api=1)
D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0x7dbce3c0) (w:296 h:95 s:320 f:0x1 u:b00)
D/View: [Warning] assignParent to null: this = android.widget.LinearLayout{4a286c1 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-296,95}
I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=252KB, data=213KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=195KB, data=154KB
I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("94FEE1288ACA65E1FE88062ABB81C202") to get test ads on this device.
D/AudioManager: getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
D/AudioManager: getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
D/EgretLoader: EgretLoader(Context context)
    The context is not activity
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 2
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out: e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
W/Ads: Error while pinging URL: https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/gen_204?is_aia=false&id=gmob-apps-report-exception&os=8.1.0&api=27&device=Xiaomi%20Redmi%206A&js=afma-sdk-a-v16187999.15000000.1&appid=com.toprograms.bookstat&exceptiontype=com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.a&stacktrace=com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.a%3A%20Unable%20to%20obtain%20a%20JavascriptEngine.%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.o.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A1)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.promise.g.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.h.run(Unknown%20Source%3A4)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ab.execute(Unknown%20Source%3A0)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.x.run(Unknown%20Source%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.w.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ae.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A6)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.promise.e.d(Unknown%20Source%3A7)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.at.a(Unknown%20Source%3A7)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.promise.g.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.h.run(Unknown%20Source%3A4)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ab.execute(Unknown%20Source%3A0)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.x.run(Unknown%20Source%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.w.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ae.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A6)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.promise.e.d(Unknown%20Source%3A7)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.ad.run(Unknown%20Source%3A5)%0A%09at%20android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java%3A794)%0A%09at%20android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java%3A99)%0A%09at%20aam.a(Unknown%20Source%3A0)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.e.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A1)%0A%09at%20aam.dispatchMessage(Unknown%20Source%3A0)%0A%09at%20android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java%3A176)%0A%09at%20android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java%3A6662)%0A%09at%20java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native%20Method)%0A%09at%20com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit%24MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java%3A547)%0A%09at%20com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java%3A873)%0A&eids=318482963%2C318475418%2C%2C318482077%2C318484496%2C318482761%2C318484676%2C318484568%2C318483611%2C318485399&exceptionkey=ConfigLoader.maybeFetchNewAppSettings&cl=249178941&rc=dev&session_id=5532137493713157666&sampling_rate=1&pb_tm=1.0. Unable to resolve host "pagead2.googlesyndication.com": No address associated with hostname
I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("94FEE1288ACA65E1FE88062ABB81C202") to get test ads on this device.
D/AudioManager: getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
D/AudioManager: getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=252KB, data=205KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=252KB, data=205KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB
D/EgretLoader: EgretLoader(Context context)
D/EgretLoader: The context is not activity
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 2
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out: e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
W/Ads: Error while pinging URL: https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/gen_204?is_aia=false&id=gmob-apps-report-exception&os=8.1.0&api=27&device=Xiaomi%20Redmi%206A&js=afma-sdk-a-v16187999.15000000.1&appid=com.toprograms.bookstat&exceptiontype=com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.a&stacktrace=com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.a%3A%20Unable%20to%20obtain%20a%20JavascriptEngine.%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.o.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A1)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.promise.g.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.h.run(Unknown%20Source%3A4)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ab.execute(Unknown%20Source%3A0)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.x.run(Unknown%20Source%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.w.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ae.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A6)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.promise.e.d(Unknown%20Source%3A7)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.at.a(Unknown%20Source%3A7)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.promise.g.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.h.run(Unknown%20Source%3A4)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ab.execute(Unknown%20Source%3A0)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.x.run(Unknown%20Source%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.w.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ae.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A6)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.promise.e.d(Unknown%20Source%3A7)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.ad.run(Unknown%20Source%3A5)%0A%09at%20android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java%3A794)%0A%09at%20android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java%3A99)%0A%09at%20aam.a(Unknown%20Source%3A0)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.e.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A1)%0A%09at%20aam.dispatchMessage(Unknown%20Source%3A0)%0A%09at%20android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java%3A176)%0A%09at%20android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java%3A6662)%0A%09at%20java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native%20Method)%0A%09at%20com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit%24MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java%3A547)%0A%09at%20com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java%3A873)%0A&eids=318482963%2C318475418%2C%2C318482077%2C318484496%2C318482761%2C318484676%2C318484568%2C318483611%2C318485399&exceptionkey=ConfigLoader.maybeFetchNewAppSettings&cl=249178941&rc=dev&session_id=5532137493713157666&sampling_rate=1&pb_tm=1.0. Unable to resolve host "pagead2.googlesyndication.com": No address associated with hostname
I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("94FEE1288ACA65E1FE88062ABB81C202") to get test ads on this device.
D/AudioManager: getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
D/AudioManager: getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
D/EgretLoader: EgretLoader(Context context)
    The context is not activity
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 2
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out: e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
W/Ads: Error while pinging URL: https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/gen_204?is_aia=false&id=gmob-apps-report-exception&os=8.1.0&api=27&device=Xiaomi%20Redmi%206A&js=afma-sdk-a-v16187999.15000000.1&appid=com.toprograms.bookstat&exceptiontype=com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.a&stacktrace=com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.a%3A%20Unable%20to%20obtain%20a%20JavascriptEngine.%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.o.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A1)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.promise.g.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.h.run(Unknown%20Source%3A4)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ab.execute(Unknown%20Source%3A0)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.x.run(Unknown%20Source%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.w.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ae.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A6)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.promise.e.d(Unknown%20Source%3A7)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.at.a(Unknown%20Source%3A7)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.promise.g.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.h.run(Unknown%20Source%3A4)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ab.execute(Unknown%20Source%3A0)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.x.run(Unknown%20Source%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.w.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ae.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A6)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.promise.e.d(Unknown%20Source%3A7)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.ad.run(Unknown%20Source%3A5)%0A%09at%20android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java%3A794)%0A%09at%20android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java%3A99)%0A%09at%20aam.a(Unknown%20Source%3A0)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.e.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A1)%0A%09at%20aam.dispatchMessage(Unknown%20Source%3A0)%0A%09at%20android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java%3A176)%0A%09at%20android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java%3A6662)%0A%09at%20java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native%20Method)%0A%09at%20com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit%24MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java%3A547)%0A%09at%20com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java%3A873)%0A&eids=318482963%2C318475418%2C%2C318482077%2C318484496%2C318482761%2C318484676%2C318484568%2C318483611%2C318485399&exceptionkey=ConfigLoader.maybeFetchNewAppSettings&cl=249178941&rc=dev&session_id=5532137493713157666&sampling_rate=1&pb_tm=1.0. Unable to resolve host "pagead2.googlesyndication.com": No address associated with hostname
I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("94FEE1288ACA65E1FE88062ABB81C202") to get test ads on this device.
D/AudioManager: getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
D/AudioManager: getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
D/EgretLoader: EgretLoader(Context context)
    The context is not activity
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 2
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out: e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
W/Ads: Error while pinging URL: https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/gen_204?is_aia=false&id=gmob-apps-report-exception&os=8.1.0&api=27&device=Xiaomi%20Redmi%206A&js=afma-sdk-a-v16187999.15000000.1&appid=com.toprograms.bookstat&exceptiontype=com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.a&stacktrace=com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.a%3A%20Unable%20to%20obtain%20a%20JavascriptEngine.%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.o.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A1)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.promise.g.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.h.run(Unknown%20Source%3A4)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ab.execute(Unknown%20Source%3A0)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.x.run(Unknown%20Source%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.w.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ae.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A6)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.promise.e.d(Unknown%20Source%3A7)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.at.a(Unknown%20Source%3A7)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.promise.g.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.h.run(Unknown%20Source%3A4)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ab.execute(Unknown%20Source%3A0)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.x.run(Unknown%20Source%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.w.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A2)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ae.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A6)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.promise.e.d(Unknown%20Source%3A7)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.ad.run(Unknown%20Source%3A5)%0A%09at%20android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java%3A794)%0A%09at%20android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java%3A99)%0A%09at%20aam.a(Unknown%20Source%3A0)%0A%09at%20com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.e.a(%3Acom.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite%4020290003%4020290003.249178941.249178941%3A1)%0A%09at%20aam.dispatchMessage(Unknown%20Source%3A0)%0A%09at%20android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java%3A176)%0A%09at%20android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java%3A6662)%0A%09at%20java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native%20Method)%0A%09at%20com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit%24MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java%3A547)%0A%09at%20com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java%3A873)%0A&eids=318482963%2C318475418%2C%2C318482077%2C318484496%2C318482761%2C318484676%2C318484568%2C318483611%2C318485399&exceptionkey=ConfigLoader.maybeFetchNewAppSettings&cl=249178941&rc=dev&session_id=5532137493713157666&sampling_rate=1&pb_tm=1.0. Unable to resolve host "pagead2.googlesyndication.com": No address associated with hostname
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 263841
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 30004637
D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=263841, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainBottom, firebase_screen_id(_si)=7354846573346929613}]
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x8c516000,api=1)
D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0x80020900) (w:720 h:1440 s:736 f:0x1 u:b00)
    unregister, handle(0x80a06fc0) (w:720 h:1440 s:736 f:0x1 u:b00)
    unregister, handle(0x80a06e40) (w:720 h:1440 s:736 f:0x1 u:b00)
```

Файл вроде и на месте, получен, но в тоже время его нет. Что делать?

Comment: Существование имени файла совсем не означает существования файла с таким именем.

Comment: @Эникейщик, но ведь файл открылся в логах видно. Но почему с ним не могу работать? Причём на андроидах ниже 8.0 всё работает, выше нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение оказалось довольно простым. Там где пользователь выбрал файл, его нужно сохранить в виде URI(у меня это была строка). И при открытии использовать не uri.getPath(), а именно сам URI. В моём случае использовать File уже не нужно было.